# Can't Open Main.Storyboard

Tags: interface, storyboard, program-entry-point, builder

The document "Main.storyboard" could not be opened. The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.InterfaceBuilder error -1.)

-- that's the error I keep receiving. After doing some research, apparently I need to switch all my fonts from attributed to plain but I can't access my storyboard file so how am I supposed to do that? Or is there another solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same issue when pull the code from the github:
It occur due to duplicate of identifier. Some of the file name are again reuse. Click on StoryBoard->open source code remove duplicate identifier.
You find indentifer name click on error. copy the whole error message.

This will works for me.``